# Eclipse RCP Title Bar Color

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is there a way we can change the RCP application's title bar color ? The default is dark blue in Windows. But is there any way we can change the color of the title bar..

If that is not possible, is it possible to change the color of the TITLE in the title bar ?

I would be launching two instances of the same application in my machine. I need a way to differentiate these two instances just by looking at it by means of color.

If the above is not possible, could you please give some ideas as to how to differentiate these two instances by means of color coding?

Thanks,

Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible to change the title bar color. The reason is that SWT trys to look like a native windows, mac or linux applicaiton.
So you must configure the title in the preferences of your OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there any other way that we can differentiate the two instances which i have? I know i can the change the color of the View tabs. But I want something to be seen globally.